# Issues in structure conversion from C++ to C# .Net Compact Framework

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke, windows-embedded-compact

I am converting c/c++ structures into C# standards.

C/C++ Structures:

```
 typedef struct _sta_conn_info{
STA_CONNECT_STATE               connect_state;//Enum
STA_ASSOC_STATE                 assoc_state;//Enum
unsigned char               bssid[6];
unsigned char               ssid[34];   
unsigned long               channel;
enum mode               mode;//Enum
unsigned long               signalStrength; 
    unsigned long               noiseLevel;     
STA_AUTH_ALG                    auth_alg;//enum
STA_ENCRYPT_ALG                 encrypt_alg;//enum  
}STA_CONN_INFO;


 typedef struct _NDISUIO_QUERY_OID
         {
           NDIS_OID        Oid;
           PTCHAR          ptcDeviceName;  
           UCHAR           Data[sizeof(ULONG)];
         } NDISUIO_QUERY_OID, *PNDISUIO_QUERY_OID;
```

Respective C# structures:

```
     [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct _sta_conn_info
    {
        public _sta_connect_state       connect_state;      
        public _sta_assoc_state         assoc_state; 

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst = 6)]
        public char[]               bssid ;//= new char[6];

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst = 34)]
        public char[]               ssid ;//= new char[34]  

        public uint         channel;
        public mode             mode;
        public uint             signalStrength; 
            public uint             noiseLevel;     
        public _sta_auth_alg            auth_alg;
        public _sta_encrypt_alg         encrypt_alg;
         }

    QUERY STRUCT:   
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]

    public struct _NDISUIO_QUERY_OID
    {
        public uint        Oid;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string          ptcDeviceName;
        public byte[] Data;
    };
```

I converted the data types using this >>>[reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9714/Win-API-C-to-NET)

`Marshal.SizeOf()` is working in WIN CE. I tested it.

If my structure conversion is fine then definitely `Marshal.SizeOf()` will work to get the size of the structure, but it is throwing exceptions and returning `error code 87` in DeviceIoControl() API.

Can anyone clarify me about the conversions and let me know If I did anything wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `bssid` and `ssid` the C++ declarations are:

```
unsigned char bssid[6];
unsigned char ssid[34];
```

Now, `unsigned char` is a single byte and is typically used for byte arrays rather than text. So the C# should be:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst = 6)]
public byte[] bssid ;//= new byte[6];

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst = 34)]
public byte[] ssid ;//= new byte[34]
```

Your use of `char` in the C# is not correct because `char` is two bytes wide in C#.

In `_NDISUIO_QUERY_OID` where you have

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = sizeof(uint))]
public byte[] Data;
```

I believe that you need to use `ByValArray` rather than `ByValTStr`. But as we have discussed in many of your recent questions, the exact meaning of this member is unclear. Is it really a fixed length byte array, or is it a variable length buffer? Do you have sample C++ code that works? That would settle the debate once and for all.

---

OK, from the header `nuiouser.h` header file I have this:

```
//
//  Structure to go with IOCTL_NDISUIO_QUERY_OID_VALUE.
//  The Data part is of variable length, determined by
//  the input buffer length passed to DeviceIoControl.
//
typedef struct _NDISUIO_QUERY_OID
{
    NDIS_OID        Oid;

#ifdef UNDER_CE
    //
    //  In CE land app is allowed to query without having to do
    //  IOCTL_NDISUIO_OPEN_DEVICE
    //  Hence the device name to query argument needed..
    //  For app that does IOCTL_NDISUIO_OPEN_DEVICE this argument
    //  is then not necessary..
    //

    PTCHAR          ptcDeviceName;  
#endif

    UCHAR           Data[sizeof(ULONG)];

} NDISUIO_QUERY_OID, *PNDISUIO_QUERY_OID;
```

Which tells you conclusively that `Data` is variable length. You'll need to allocate the struct with `AllocHGlobal` and do all the marshalling by hand I am afraid.

Comment: Sir.. 
Array conversion is useful one,

sir how to initialize those arrays ??

we can have new byte[size]; but where can I initialize in the code??

or can we maintain any constructor??

without initializing the arrays `Marshal.Sizeof()` is throwing the exceptions.

In C/C++ we have this flexibility

`unsigned char bssid[6]; `

Comment: You could certainly use a constructor. Or a static method that returned a new instance of the struct.

Comment: Sir



[This Qn will describe my complete task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639086/issues-in-conversion-of-code-from-c-to-c-sharp-to-achieve-the-required-task-as)

Comment: I don't have anything more to add. I think I've answered the question you ask here. You are going to have to accept that you need to perform manual marshalling for `NDISUIO_QUERY_OID`. That is now clear.

Comment: Sir

yep.. For conversion related problem you suggested me a way to do. 

Thanks !!

Comment: I think your only outstanding problem now is how to marshal `NDISUIO_QUERY_OID`. You need `AllocHGlobal`, after you've worked out the size needed. And then you need `Marshal.Copy` or `Marshal.WriteXXX` or whatever works on CE!

Comment: Thanks Sir..!! I ll try in this way !! :)